# bind syntax in scalaz

Tags: bind, implicit-conversion, scalaz

Is there a way to use nice haskell-bind (`>>`) syntax in scalaz, to write the code that way: `monad1 >> monad2`?

ToBindOps requires explicit monad to be passed, so I have to do something like
 `ToBindOps[F, Unit](monad1) >> monad2`
in oder to get access to `>>`, which is already an overkill,
because `monad1 >>= (_ => monad2)` is simpler.

( In my particular case monad1 is `Free[A, B]`, so I have a `>>=` "for free", but the need for bind pops up quite often for other monads as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by importing an object `scalaz.syntax.monad` (or `scalaz.syntax.bind`). This will bring an implicit instance of `BindOps` to the scope:

```
import scalaz.effect.IO
import scalaz.syntax.monad._

IO.putStrLn("Hello!") >> IO.putStrLn("How are you?")
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. Actually it was already working in my case, but IntelliJ have tricked me, and highlighted `>>` as an error (could not find symbol). The code compiles and runs successfully, so I will address it to Intellij scala plugin.

Comment: @ISeeVoices Yes, IntelliJ IDEA sometimes does not play well with Scalaz.